# glfw segfaults after initialization

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, glfw, glew

I built glfw, and the programs in test run just fine, however, when I try to write my own program it segfaults at the line `while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))` and when I remove this it segfaults on `glfwPollEvents()`. I am compiling it with `cc window.c -lglfw3 -lGLEW -lGL -lX11 -lGLU -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi -lm -lXinerama -lXcursor`. Why do these functions segfault, and why don't the initialization functions. Full program included bellow.

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "gl", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glfwPollEvents();
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glfwTerminate();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never check `window` to make sure it's non-**NULL**. It's possible you're failing to create a window because of your specific combination of version and profile hints.

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to you initialization:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
```

And then it will work! ;-)

You are probably using a Mac, right? The explanation is right here:
http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-opengl-30-context

Comment: The libraries listed above are for X11 so it's more likely to be Linux.

Comment: I'm porting my app to Mac and this was one of the only issues I had. Your solution provided the answer. Thanks